# Fieldstone on Ebal Altar

Tags: deuteronomy

I was wondering if the fieldstone found on the Altar on Mt. Ebal has any other names or a proper name, or what its composition might be of? If anyone knows? I am assuming what is fieldstone in Kansas or Germany is not necessarily the same as what was found on Mt. Ebal?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Valid questions here need a specific text to discuss.

Comment: What is a field stone

Comment: please edit your post to include biblical references. As it stands now it doesn't belong on this site

Comment: @Michael16 asks "*What is a field stone*". [Fieldstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieldstone) is very common in Kansas and most of the world north of that. The old joke asks what a farmer field grows, and he replies "stones". These are generally rounded and most are less than a couple of feet in diameter. They were created and deposited by the ice age. Each winter, the freezing ground pushes them upward, and each spring the field "grows" a new batch of stones. Many farms have fieldstone walls around them, illustrating the practicality of farmers, who solve two problems with one stone.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP is referring to the structure of fieldstones found on Mt. Ebal, it is known by various names. The easiest to remember is [Joshua's Altar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Ebal_site), even though it was probably not erected by him, and is not an actual altar.  As far as the stones themselves are concerned, a fieldstone is "any architectural stone used in its natural shape." The particular type of fieldstone is beyond the scope of this site.

[image]

The biblical accounts relating to the site are found in Deuteronomy 27

> 2 On the day you cross the Jordan into the land which the Lord, your
> God, is giving you, set up some large stones and coat them with
> plaster. 3 Write on them, at the time you cross, all the words of this
> law, so that you may enter the land which the Lord, your God, is
> giving you, a land flowing with milk and honey, just as the Lord, the
> God of your ancestors, promised you. 4 When you cross the Jordan, on
> Mount Ebal you shall set up these stones concerning which I command
> you today, and coat them with plaster, 5 and you shall build there an
> altar to the Lord, your God, an altar made of stones that no iron tool
> has touched. 6 You shall build this altar of the Lord, your God, with
> unhewn stones, and shall offer on it burnt offerings to the Lord, your
> God.

And Joshua 8:

> On Mount Ebal, Joshua built to the Lord, the God of Israel, an altar
> 31 of unhewn stones on which no iron tool had been used, just as
> Moses, the servant of the Lord, had commanded the Israelites, as
> recorded in the book of the law. On this altar they sacrificed burnt
> offerings to the Lord and made communion sacrifices. 32 There, in the
> presence of the Israelites, Joshua inscribed upon the stones a copy of
> the law written by Moses.

The Wikipedia article on Joshua's altar says 'the identification is uncertain because "there are considerable difficulties in identifying the main structure as an altar: the difference between this structure and other Israelite altars"; However, [archaeologist Israel] Finkelstein believes that this is indeed a ritual site.'

Comment: The May/June issue of *Beyond Today* magazine has an article, [*More Proof of the Bible: Mount Ebal Discoveries*](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/beyond-today-magazine/more-proof-of-the-bible-mount-ebal-discoveries), which supplies some interesting new discoveries.
It says that the original altar might actually be the 6-foot circular structure beneath the external structure, and that a "curse amulet" has been found there, with the inscription "*Cursed, cursed, cursed—cursed by the God YWH. / You will die cursed. / Cursed you will surely die. / Cursed by YWH—cursed, cursed, cursed*".